# Typescript "this" issue

Tags: typescript, this

I am new with typescript. Trying to create an abstract class for html form. I want to execute some custom code on form submit. Therefore, assigning a function to this.onsubmit. Problem is, the submit method  requires the first parameter to be "this" but I need "this" to access class members as well.

```
export abstract class AbstractForm {
 protected form: HTMLFormElement;

 constructor(form: HTMLFormElement) {
    this.form = form;
    this.form.onsubmit = this.Submit;
 }

 private Submit(this: HTMLElement, ev: Event) {
    if (this.PreSubmissionValidation()) { // Error
        // Some code
    }
    ev.preventDefault();
 }
 abstract PreSubmissionValidation(): boolean;
 abstract OnSuccess(): any;
 abstract OnError(): any;
}
```

Comment: What about just binding? `this.form.onsubmit = this.Submit.bind(this);`? I advise against calling your first parameter `this` - very confusing, as it's not the value of `this` in the context of `AbstractForm`.

Comment: I'm really curious why there's has a parameter that HAS to be called this... ?  What tech lead is gonna let this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could do something ugly like this instead:

```
private readonly Submit = (() => {
    const instance = this;
    return function (this: HTMLElement, ev: Event) {
        if (instance.PreSubmissionValidation()) {

        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: "this" is brilliant.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: This won't work actually, `this` parameters are removed by the TypeScript compiler. See my answer.

Comment: @Tao: I checked the compiled code, it works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry... I shouldn't be posting today, second mistake from my side already...

Comment: @Tao: It's fine :)